# Best way to join two red-black trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, red-black-tree

The easiest way is to store two trees in two arrays, merge them and build a new red-black tree with a sorted array which takes O(m + n) times.

Is there an algorithm with less time complexity?

Answer (score 4):

You can merge two red-black trees in time **O(m log(n/m + 1))** where n and m are the input sizes and, WLOG, m ≤ n. Notice that this bound is tighter than O(m+n). Here's some intuition:

- When the two trees are similar in size (m ≈ n), the bound is approximately O(m) = O(n) = O(n + m).
- When one tree is significantly larger than the other (m ≪ n), the bound is approximately O(log n).

You can find a brief description of the algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Set_operations_and_bulk_operations). A more in-depth description which generalizes to other balancing schemes (AVL, BB[α], Treap, ...) can be found in a [recent paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/BFS16.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you have a generic Sets (so generic red-black tree) you can't choose the solution which was suggested @Sam Westrick. Because he assumes that all  elements in the first set are less then the elements in the second set. Also into the Cormen (the best book to learn algorithm and data structures) specifies this condition to join two red-black tree.

Comment: Actually no, this is not the case. In the literature, there is a special function called "join" which is used as a helper function in more complicated algorithms. This special "join" has restrictions like you mention. But the general merge/union algorithm does not have any requirements on its inputs, and still manages O(m log(n/m)) complexity.

Comment: On the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Set_operations_and_bulk_operations), scroll down a little to see the function "union" for more details! This general "union" function is the algorithm I describe in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Due to the fact that you need to compare each `element` in both `m` and `n` `Red-Black Trees`, you will have to deal with a minimum of `O(m+n)` time complexity, there's a way to do it `O(1)` space complexity, but that is something else which has nothing to do with your qu. if you are not iterating and checking each `element` in each `Red-Black Tree`, you cannot guarantee that your new `Red-Black Tree` will be sorted. I can think of another way of merging two `Red-Black Trees`, which called "In-Place Merge using DLL", but this one would also result `O(m+n)` time complexity.

1. Convert the given two `Red-Black Trees` into `Doubly Linked List`, which has `O(m+n)` time complexity.
2. Merge the two sorted `Linked Lists`, which has `O(m+n)` time complexity.
3. Build a Balanced `Red-Black Tree` from the merged `list` created in step 2, which has `O(m+n)` time complexity.

Time complexity of this method is also `O(m+n)`.

So due to the fact you have to compare the elements each Tree with the other elements of the other Tree, you will have to end up with at least `O(m+n)`.

Comment: This is not true. In particular, you do not have to inspect each of the m+n elements. The optimal bound is O(m log(n/m + 1)), which is tighter than O(m + n). For some intuition on why this is possible, consider that the standard *insertion* algorithm is basically the same thing as a union algorithm when one of the trees contains only a single element, and yet insertion has logarithmic time complexity.